# Can anyone tell me what f[[1,1,2]] is doing?

Tags: core-language

```
equ = DSolve[y'[x] == x + y[x], y[x], x];
y[x] /. equ;
f = equ[[1, 1, 2]];
```

Comment: Take a look at `Part` in den Documentation.

Comment: [The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html)

Comment: @Karsten Well, it should be the "Five Kinds of Bracketing (and increasing)", considering `<|...|>`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Tell [them](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html) (using **Give Feedback** in the lower right corner). I recently came across too many places in the documentation, that are not up to date with the ever increasing number of symbols.

Answer (score 2):

When you are uncertain about what *Mathematica* will do, don't suppress output by adding a terminating semi-colon ( ; ), so you can study and learn from the results.

```
eq = DSolve[y'[x] == x + y[x], y[x], x]
```

> `{{y[x] -> -1 - x + E^x C[1]}}`

```
eq[[1, 1, 2]]
```

> `-1 - x + E^x C[1]`

You also need to know that `eq[[1, 1, 2]]` is the short form for

```
Part[eq, 1, 1, 2]
```

which you can determine for yourself by evaluating

```
Hold[eq[[1, 1, 2]]] // FullForm
```

Using `Hold` and `FullForm` in this way is something you will find useful in many situations where *Mathematica* does the unexpected.

You should also read the documentation for [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) -- it is really fundamental to your understanding of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Thnx for your help ....but in eq[[1, 1, 2]] I want to know what 1,1,2 represents....if possible help me with example...

Comment: @Allinformation These indices indicate a portion of the expression for `eq`, with the indices referring to successively deeper levels of `eq//FullForm`.  As others have suggested, see the documentation for `Part`.

Comment: @Allinformation. Those integers are the indexes that specify what part of the expression `eq` is to be returned. Look up `Part` in the documentation. It is explained in great detail there. Also, try evaluating `eq[[1]]` and `eq[[1]][[1]]` and `eq[[1]][[1]][[2]]` to see what each index refers to. The last is the same as `eq[[1, 1, 2]]]`.